# При написании телеграм бота на питоне выдает ошибку SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
    import random
    import telebot
    spisok=('автострада','спасибо')
    a=random.choice(spisok)
    b=(list(a))
    n=list(("*"*len(a)))

    bot = telebot.TeleBot("1081897647:AAGHBdT1VeS6xVJPAq0yhB_JfvlcAWKOT")
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def send_welcome(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет,сейчас ты сыграешь в игру виселица")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите одну букву")

  def text(message):
    s=0
    if message.text in b:
        for idx, symbol in enumerate(b):
            if symbol == message.text:
                n[idx] = symbol
        if n==b:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поздравляю")
    else:   
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Данной буквы нет")
        s+=1
        if s==5:
            return  
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: надо вынести реализацию функции отдельно, а в цикле только её вызывать, а код сюда принято кодом выставлять

Comment: Давайте начнём с того, что вы в цикле создаёте бесконечное количество копий функции. Зачем?

Comment: не совсем понимаю как это реализовать(

Comment: @илья скиньте код текстом

Comment: @SKIP добавил код

Comment: Это там в инициализации прям токен?

Comment: @bonursk да,он самый

Answer (score 1):

> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Смотрим,где у Вас *break*?
Насколько я вижу, в одном-единственном месте. Внутри описания ФУНКЦИИ:

```
def text(message):
    s=0
    if message.text in b:
      . . .
    else:
      . . .
        if s==5:
           break
```

И где Вы видите здесь ЦИКЛ, внутри которого должен стоять оператор *break*?
Если Вы, на самом деле, в этой точке программы желаете завершить вовсе не выполнение некоего несуществующего цикла, а выполнение функции, то надо и ставить -  *return*!

Comment: я полностью убрал цикл,но после достижения s==5, программа не завершается.Код изменил в посте

Comment: @илья *программа не завершается* - но я не вижу текста **программы**! Как же я могу ответить на этот вопрос?! Я вижу текст **функции**, в которой переменной *s* сначала присваивается значение 0, а потом (возможно) это значение увеличивается до 1. Но переменная *s*  **никогда** не примет значение равное 5.